# Retrieving data attributes of *all* child elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get all data attribute of child elements in the form of an array.

I tried with

```
"data_array" : $('#rule-list').children().data('fruits')


 <div class="fruit-list" id="fruit-list">
        <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="apple,mango; pineapple, watermelon">every month for 5 times</span>
        <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="banana,kiwi">every May and November for 5 times</span>
    </div>
```

the expected output should be

```
data_array = [[apple,mango; pineapple, watermelon],[banana,kiwi]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like this

```
var fruitArray=[] // Array to contain array of fruits
// will get all children
var getChild = $("#fruit-list").children();
// loop over them
getChild.each(function(i,v){
// push in fruits array, an array of data-fruit
fruitArray.push([($(v).data('fruit'))])
})
console.log(fruitArray)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gj6czkko/2/)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to return the attribute values of *each* array element rather than that of a single element, you cannot use [`jQuery#data(key)`](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2) (because it only returns the `data-*` attribute of the *first* element in the jQuery collection).

I would suggest using `getAttribute` within a call to [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead:

```js
var fruitList = document.getElementById('fruit-list')

var dataArray = [].map.call(fruitList.children, function (e) {
  return e.getAttribute('data-fruit')
})

console.log(dataArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruit-list" id="fruit-list">
        <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="apple,mango; pineapple, watermelon">every month for 5 times</span>
        <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="banana,kiwi">every May and November for 5 times</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-fruit]');
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    result.push([elements[i].dataset.fruit]);
}

console.log(result);
```

```html
<div class="fruit-list" id="fruit-list">
<span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="apple,mango; pineapple, watermelon">every month for 5 times</span>
<span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="banana,kiwi">every May and November for 5 times</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selector `"#fruit-list [data-fruit]"` `$.map()`, `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\w+/` as parameter to match one or more word characters, return an array with return value of `.match()` to get result of multi-dimensional array

```js
var arr = $.map($("#fruit-list [data-fruit]"), function(el) {
  return Array($(el).data("fruit").match(/\w+/g))
});

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruit-list" id="fruit-list">
  <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="apple,mango; pineapple, watermelon">every month for 5 times</span>
  <span class="chips" title="Click to remove" data-fruit="banana,kiwi">every May and November for 5 times</span>
</div>
```